# If $F(x,y,z) = \frac xzf(u,v),$ find $\partial^2F/\partial x^2$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

$F(x,y,z) = \frac xzf(u(x,y),v(x,y))$;
$u(x,y) = xy$ ,
$v(x,y) = y/x$

I calculated the first derivatives with respect to $x,y$, and $z$.

How do I calculate $∂^2F/∂x^2$?

I know that $$∂^2F/∂x^2 = \frac{∂}{∂x}\frac{∂F}{∂x} = \frac∂{∂x} \Big(\frac1z f(u,v) + \frac{xy}z \frac{∂f}{∂u} - \frac y{zx^2} \frac{∂f}{∂v}\Big)$$

How do I proceed further?

Comment: Once over in the same vein! By the way: The factor in front of ${\partial f\over\partial v}$ should be $-{y\over zx}$.

Comment: Ok. I just want to know how do i partial differentiate f(u,v) and the other stuff in between the paranthesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are given
$$F(x,y,z):={x\over z} f\bigl(u(x,y),v(x,y)\bigr)$$
with
$$u(x,y)=x\>y,\qquad v(x,y)={y\over x}\ .$$
The derivatives of the "inner functions" are then
$$u_x=y,\qquad v_x=-{y\over x^2}\ ,$$
and we obtain
$${\partial F\over\partial x}={1\over z}f(u,v)+{x\over z}(f_u u_x+f_v v_x)={1\over z}f(u,v)+{xy\over z}f_u-{y\over xz}f_v\ ,\tag{1}$$
more or less in accordance with your own result.

In order to partially differentiate with respect to $x$ again we have to repeat this procedure: Differentiate products according to the product rule, and differentiate  composite functions according to the chain rule. The partial derivatives $f_u$ and $f_v$ appearing in $(1)$ are "outer functions" of $u$ and $v$, as $f$ was an "outer function" of $u$ and $v$ when we computed the first derivative. Therefore one has
$${\partial f_u\over\partial x}=(f_u)_u\>u_x+(f_u)_v\>v_x=f_{uu}\>u_x+f_{uv}\>v_x\ .$$In this way we obtain
$$\eqalign{{\partial^2 F\over\partial x^2}&={1\over z}\left(f_u\> y+f_v{-y\over x^2}\right)+{y\over z}f_u+{xy\over z}\left(f_{uu}\> y+f_{uv}{-y\over x^2}\right)+{y\over x^2z}f_v-{y\over xz}\left(f_{vu}\> y+f_{vv}{-y\over x^2}\right)\cr 
&={2y\over z}f_u+{xy^2\over z}f_{uu}-{2y^2\over xz}f_{uv}+{y^2\over x^3 z}f_{vv}\ .\cr}$$

Comment: I got lost in those notations. What do you mean by 'fuy' and fvuy in the second derivative? (I'm sorry but have no idea how to write index letters or numbers)

Comment: Can you explain how do you derive the formulas for fv and fu? Why is the derivative of fv = (fvuy + fvv -y/x^2) ? This is the thing that I don't understand.

Comment: @Tamás: See my edit.